# JavaScript Hidden iFrame comet

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, comet

I need to implement comet, preferably with the hidden "forever iFrame" technique using PHP to instantly update a file on the server and get data from that file (and then JavaScript would use that data to manipulate the webpage). I have been searching for a detailed example for how to do something like this. Much of what I have found I do not understand or I think is not applicable. I am not fluent in PHP, yet.

If anyone knows or knows how to find a detailed example of this or could make one, I would be much obliged.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure this is close to what you want:
http://code.jenseng.com/jenChat/

The guy even mocks the technique as preposterously outdated, but it's exactly what you need. Be warned, as I seem to remember, there's a little bug in the actual code which stops it from working out the box, like some erroneous filehandle. 
Get back to me here if you can't spot it. I can assure you the code works perfectly once the error is spotted. I think it's in chat.php, I'm checking.

Comment: Yo hope you like it...plus me is a nice motivator ;)